# cypher support in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, neo4j, cypher

I wanna develop an Android project with Neo4j database. Does Android Studio have cypher support, if so which version?

I tried several code for connection from Android Studio Electric Eel to Neo4j 4.4.19 version. But it didn't work.

Comment: Provide details in your question of what you tried. Also, what kind of "support" are you looking for (editing Cypher code, sending requests to neo4j server, ...)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.